# Python if-elif argv return

Tags: python

I want to make a script in python that will work with my argv's, but when I am trying this simple if-elif, it returns me nothing

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        add = str(sys.argv[1])
        print add
elif len(sys.argv) == 2:
        add = str(sys.argv[1])
        add2 = str(sys.argv[2])
        print add + add2
elif len(sys.argv) > 4:
        print "too many"
```

Can someone explain me why when I am running the script like this:

`$ python test.py 5 6`

and the result is nothing, only if I am running this one

`$ python test.py 5 6 7 8` the result is too many

Comment: If you print `sys.argv`, the reason will become apparent.

Comment: also you don't have a case for `len(sys.argv) == 3`, so when you run `python test.py 5 6` you get nothing

Comment: Also, have in mind that `if len(sys.argv) == 1:` and then accessing `add = str(sys.argv[1])` will raise an IndexError. That should be `sys.argv[0]`.

Comment: To read parameters Python contains module `argparse`. A more advanced option and also allows optional parameters https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html

Comment: but when I want to check if in my command line I have special options, like -i, -m ...
how I can do this, I tried like this, but no way...
if len(sys.argv) == 3:
        if sys.argv[2] == "-i":
                add = str(sys.argv[3])
                print add

Comment: I wrote a example below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments and anwers already given, this program update should work fine:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) == 2:
  print(sys.argv[1])
elif len(sys.argv) == 3:
  print(str(sys.argv[1]) + str(sys.argv[2]))
elif len(sys.argv) > 3:
  print("too many")
```

I advice you to print everything which is not clear for you. With a simple `print(sys.argv)` you would have get `['test.py', '3', '4']`. I always do this kind of quick tests before going into the documentation and it saves me a lot of time ;).

Comment: but when I want to check if in my command line I have special options, like -i, -m ... how I can do this, I tried like this, but no way... if len(sys.argv) == 3: if sys.argv[2] == "-i": add = str(sys.argv[3]) print add

Comment: special options (i.e. `python test.py -i 42 --force`) work the same. When I print `sys.argv` with the previous example, I get : `['test.py', '-i', '42', '--force']`. Then  you can do `sys.argv[1] == "-i"` in your if statement without any trouble.

Comment: Ok I think I found the mistake : `if len(sys.argv) == 3: if sys.argv[1] == "-i": add = str(sys.argv[2]) print add`. Index in list starts at 0, you used index 3 which is out of bound. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Example using module `argparse`. Positional arguments are mandatory and not allow parameters, instead optional arguments allowed N parameters.

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser(description='%(prog)s is a argparse demo')

# Optional argument that requires two arguments
parser.add_argument('-two_args', nargs=2)

# Optional argument that requires 1 to N arguments
parser.add_argument('-one_n_args', nargs='+')

# Optional argument that requires 0 to N arguments
parser.add_argument('-zero_n_args', nargs='*')

args = parser.parse_args()
print 'args.two_args:', args.two_args
print 'args.one_n_args:', args.one_n_args
print 'args.zero_n_args:', args.zero_n_args
```

test:

```
C:\>python demo.py --help
usage: demo.py [-h] [-two_args TWO_ARGS TWO_ARGS]
               [-one_n_args ONE_N_ARGS [ONE_N_ARGS ...]]
               [-zero_n_args [ZERO_N_ARGS [ZERO_N_ARGS ...]]]

demo.py is demo

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -two_args TWO_ARGS TWO_ARGS
  -one_n_args ONE_N_ARGS [ONE_N_ARGS ...]
  -zero_n_args [ZERO_N_ARGS [ZERO_N_ARGS ...]]

C:\>python demo.py -two_args 1
usage: demo.py [-h] [-two_args TWO_ARGS TWO_ARGS]
               [-one_n_args ONE_N_ARGS [ONE_N_ARGS ...]]
               [-zero_n_args [ZERO_N_ARGS [ZERO_N_ARGS ...]]]
demo.py: error: argument -two_args: expected 2 argument(s)

C:\>python demo.py -two_args 1 2 -one_n_args x -zero_n_args
args.two_args: ['1', '2']
args.one_n_args: ['x']
args.zero_n_args: []

C:\>python demo.py -two_args 1 2 -one_n_args x -zero_n_args a b c d
args.two_args: ['1', '2']
args.one_n_args: ['x']
args.zero_n_args: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Time ago I wrote an entry in my blog (in Spanish, I'm sorry) http://www.3engine.net/wp/2015/02/argparse-modulo-de-analisis-de-linea-de-comandos-para-python/

Comment: I can make 2 times args = parser.parse_args() ??
like args = parser.parse_args() and args1 = parser.parse_args()

Comment: I want in 1 parser to set a default value a variable that I am creating after args = parser.parse_args()    so I have an error, if I want to use, said that is not defined that value for default

Comment: Maybe I can help yourself specify a default value, something like `parser.add_argument('-opt4', help='help for opt4', type=int, default=10)`. You can also indicate that the argument is required `parser.add_argument('-opt6', required=True)`

Comment: I did like this, but the default value is a variable that I am creating

Comment: Then maybe can help you a custom action where you must implement a class that inherits from `argparse.Action` https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#action

Answer (score 1):

`sys.argv[0]` is the name of your script. The parameters start at `1`. So in the first case, your `sys.argv` is actually something like `['test.py', '5', '6']`

Comment: yeah, I understood now, forgot that first argv is name of the script, thank you!!!

Comment: but when I want to check if in my command line I have special options, like -i, -m ... how I can do this, I tried like this, but no way... if len(sys.argv) == 3: if sys.argv[2] == "-i": add = str(sys.argv[3]) print add

Comment: @AlexV: If `len(sys.argv) == 3` then `sys.argv` is a list with 3 elements so `sys.argv[3]` **doesn't exist** . You _can_ process command line args manually, but it's much better to use a module. For Python 2.7 or later there's `argparse`, as mentioned above by  David Miró. For older Python versions you can use [getopt](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getopt.html#module-getopt).